# Unable to understand the indexOf in javascript in order to find Unique Value in String?

Tags: javascript

I have below code to check the string is unique or not.

```
function unique(str) {
  let values = [];
  for (let letter of str) {
    if (values.indexOf(letter) !== -1) {
      return false;
    }
    values.push(letter);
  }
  return true;
}

console.log(unique("abbds"));
```

I don't understand the if condition inside properly. Can anyone make me understand this concept?

Comment: `indexOf` gives you the index of a given string within an array. If no matches are found, it returns `-1` - an index that doesn't exist in arrays.

Comment: if you use the "new" `if (values.includes(letter))` instead then it reads a bit easier

Comment: Or you could just `function unique(str) { return Array.from(new Set(str)); }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what your code is doing.
You have string `abbds` and an array `values`. In the first iteration

- You check the first character `a` inside `values`

`values.indexOf("a")` which results in `-1` because `a` is not present in values.

- In this case, `values.indexOf("a")` since `a` is not inside `values` you push it inside `values`.
- If the `values` has the character in which case the `indexOf` will return the index of the first occurrence of the item.

And thus `values.indexOf(letter) !== -1` will be `true.

> The `indexOf()` method returns the first index at which a given element can be found in the array, or `-1` if it is not present.

From MDN : [Array.prototype.indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)